# Delphi - online technical tests

Tags: delphi

I have searched for some online Delphi programming tests, and except the small test for Delphi certification and several tests on [Delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/library/blquizes.htm) I did find nothing. Any ideas where I can find some Delphi online tests?

LE: defining online Delphi programming tests: - technical questions about Delphi fundamentals,Data types,classes, libraries, generics, database concepts, etc. Examples  [here](http://www.embarcadero.com.pl/uslugi/certyfikaty/delphi-developer-certification-study-guide.pdf) (Delphi Developer Certification Exam Study Guide) and [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/Interview-Questions/Programming/Delphi).

LE2: tests to take after you have read all the articles from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451495/questions-every-good-delphi-developer-should-be-able-to-answer

Comment: Please define what you mean by online programming tests. The link to Zarko Gaijic top node is not helpful.

Comment: @LURD - corrected the link and provided an example of what I'm looking for. In general, online tests to verify your Delphi technical skills.

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that there can't be one correct or best answer.

Comment: @Smasher - I agree with you. This is not a question which will be accepted. Everyone can vote the effort of the users to post here links and share useful sites for what I have asked.

Comment: @RBA, questions that can't be answered by a single post are not appropriate here. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - it specifically says that questions like this are not proper to ask here, because they can't be answered and because they invite discussion.

Comment: Any fixed set of technical questions creates an "arms race" that replaces the real job of an interviewer or interviewee.  Any question list on the internet merely serves to remove the question from my list of questions I might ask a prospective hire.  I don't need people who can google Delphi questions and tests. I need brains and real experience.  In fact, I care less what people know than what they can find out. Ergo, facts don't matter.  As JoelS says, Smart people who GTD.

Answer (score 3):

Some more Google results for [Delphi Interview Questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=delphi%20interview%20questions) which it seems is what you want:

http://www.placementpapers.us/delphi/174-latest_delphi_interview_questions.html
http://www.fyicenter.com/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=1944
http://www.interviewqueries.com/delphi/

Answer (score 1):

BrainBench (purchased by Previsor, and now SHL) offers online Delphi testing (very old tests but covers fundamentals.)

Test selection: http://www.shl.com/us/solutions/products/

Delphi test info: http://www.shl.com/us/solutions/products/docs/BB_Fact_Sheet_Delphi%206.0.pdf